# Bezier circle curve can't be manipulated? How do I do so?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, bezier-curves, hair

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqWYgrXw7Jk) guy easily does so. Examples:

[image]

[image]

Yet on the other hand, I can't? This is what happened:
[image]

If I click the middle dot as per the cursor, the vertices to manipulate the bezier circle is gone. Also, why isn't the bezier curve circle as per the video I showed? Basically, I would like to manipulate that bezier circle as per this video.

Why am I unable to do so, even though I followed the video? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to viewport overlay and change the "Curve Edit mode" to all and turn on "normals" checkbox

[image]

After that, you will be able to manipulate the curve in the same way

Comment: You should ask new questions on a different post, ask one question per post as the site is  made in that way. As many as you need, but one per post

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked.

Comment: @FrancisMikeNathan: if Emirs answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of his answer so other people know as well that it helps. Thx. And that's the way how this site works: Emir will get reputation points for this and other people don't have to keep on searching for this question. I just noticed you never did this, so please do it. thx.

Comment: Noted, I just clicked on the checkmark.