# Bezier curve can't scale

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, bezier-curves, hair

So I asked a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279266/bezier-circle-curve-cant-be-manipulated-how-do-i-do-so/279267#279267) regarding a bezier curve. Helpful as the answer was, unfortunately, I now have another issue: I can't scale as per this screenshot:

[image]
I would like to scale as the above.

Instead, I got this:
[image]

Scaling works only for one side like this:
[image]

Comment: I guess you've set a different pivot point than the guy in the tutorial... Also I see in the tutorial he scales along global Z axis, which you don't seem to do.

Comment: thanks, what you suggested worked.